# Using forms and user input to generate or curate a list of recommendations

Tags: javascript, html, forms, input, output

I am trying to create a form that takes the user's input, like their favorite scent and their budget, and generates a list of perfumes based on what the user input. I've already created a place where the user can type their favorite scent and budget and submit but I don't know where to start after the user presses the submit button.

Comment: Start with: where will I get cost data on perfumes?  I've voted to close, because the project isn't yet at the programming stage.